# PostgreSQL Admin Tool for mac os X

Tags: macos, mac, postgresql

I'm looking for desktop admin tool similar to phpPgAdmin  for POstgreSQL in Mac os X . Any recomendation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/) is a good admin tool, and works with Mac OS X. PhpPgAdmin should also work on OS X, although you'd need to install and set up PHP, which I can offer no advice on.

Answer (score 1):

PgAdmin on Mac OS X is not the same as other OSs.

For example, you can't just paste text in SQL Query Editor, it gets broken and you have to paste in scratch pad first, then copy & paste in editor. Although for administer database, tables, indexes, I still use it.

I prefer create tables, indexes and so on by commands, so I prefer Aqua Data Studio. I have tried others, but none of them satisfied me. Although Aqua is expensive, it has a student "mode" that you can try for a while, or if you are one, use as you need. Version 4.7 does not limit the time you use.

It shows databases, table structures, indexes and so on, but the really good part, to me, is the editor. When you use it, and know how to work properly, the shortcuts and "extras" are very helpful. Just make a query and hit Apple + R to export a nice XLS report. Select table name and hit Apple + D and it shows the table structure right on results panel. Type `INSERT INTO schema.table (` AND hit Apple + Alt + C and you get all fields typed, or `SELECT FROM schema.table JOIN schema.table2` AND, get your cursor right after the SELECT word, hit Apple + Alt + X to get all field "table-qualified".

Also, it has a nice import/export tool. If you receive a file which contains data you need to import and work on it, you can parse it (from CSV, XLS, SQL file or other types) and populate an existing table and even create a new table to suit the new data.

Although it has a little bug (as related here: https://serverfault.com/questions/226736/postgresql-jdbc-parse-too-slow-on-first-query), it works really fine. And can connect to other databases as well.

Comment: Another really nice tool is [0xDBE from JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/dbe/). It uses an interface very similar to IDEA and has good auto complete and query execution.

Answer (score 0):

Still in its alpha version but http://inductionapp.com/ seems like a good option as well